# how to break while loop from singleton class

Tags: python

I have a class whose function is called from `views.py` file in Django app.

`views.py`

```
def run_bot(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        curr_user = request.user
        bot = Bot(bot_data, user_detail)
        bot.run_status = 'RUN'
        bot.runningBot(waiting_hours, curr_user)

def stop_bot(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data1 = 1
        data2 = 2
        curr_user = request.user
        waiting_hours = int(request.POST['time'])
        bot = Bot(data2, data1)
        bot.run_status = 'STOP'
```

I am using the Django app to run a selenium bot. There are two buttons in the Front end UI: `Run` and `Stop`. When I click the `Run` button, the `POST` request is sent through ajax and comes to the function in `views.py` i.e. `run_bot()`. Similarly when I press `Stop` button, the `POST` request comes through `stop_bot()` function. Bot these function calls a class and their methods. I created a singleton class so that when a class instance is called from the `stop_bot()` function, it is should same as being called by the `run_bot()` function inorder to break a `while` loop.

`singleton class`

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Bot(metaclass=Singleton):

    def __init__(self, bot_data, user_detail):
       self.run_status = ' '
       ...
       ...

    def runningBot(self, waiting_hours, curr_user):

        no_loops = 0
        while True:
            if self.run_status == 'RUN':
                browser = self.initializeDriver()
                time.sleep(2)
                self.user_login(browser)
                time.sleep(2)
                self.performActions(no_loops, curr_user, browser)

                no_loops += 1
                browser.quit()
                time.sleep(waiting_hours)
                # time.sleep(3600 * waiting_hours)

            elif self.run_status == 'STOP':
                break
```

When `Stop` is clicked it should stop the loop when the current loop ends. But it isnt stopping. What should be done?

Comment: Where does `stop_bot` get called in this code?

Comment: `run_status` won't change inside the `runningBot` method. It's just a local variable.

Comment: @JeffUK `stop_bot()` gets called from the front end via ajax

Comment: @Wups then what should I do?

Comment: you could use an instance variable `self.run_status` and manipulate that from `stop_bot`: `bot.run_status = "STOP"`

Comment: @Wups But as far as I know, instances can't be changed in the singleton class right? Then how will this work?

Comment: You can change the attributes of a singleton instance. You just can't create a new instance.

Comment: @Wups hey I updated the code according to you suggestion. You can see it above. Will that work?

Comment: Regarding "will it work?". How about you just try it and tell us? I will never understand the whole "Here are the changes I made. Will it work?" mentality. Just test the code and find out.